# How do I set up a hotkey for an sshpass connection?

Tags: ssh, xfce

I am attempting to set up a keyboard shortcut that would open an ssh terminal, automatically connecting me to a specific server on which I can then interactively run commands.

The destination server can only be reached via a gateway, and key-based authentication is disabled.

I have successfully used sshpass to make the connection enitrely passwordless, so I avoid having to type my password twice.

**My command works if run it in an open terminal**

All works if I open a terminal and run the command:

```
sshpass -f ~/pass.txt ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -f ~/pass.txt ssh -W %h:%p myname@gateway.edu" myname@destination.edu
```

I am left with a terminal in which I can type commands to be executed by the destination server.

**I don't get a persistent terminal whens using a hotkey for the same command**

When I bind the above to a keyboard shortcut and use it, no terminal pops up on my screen (perhaps unsurprisingly).

I tried following [a previous StackExchange suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980720/open-xfce-terminal-window-and-run-command-in-same-window) specific to my OS, Xubuntu, to open a terminal and subsequently run a command via a sinle keyboard shortcut. I bound the command below:

```
xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c "sshpass -f ~/pass.txt ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -f ~/pass.txt ssh -W %h:%p myname@gateway.edu" myname@destination.edu; bash"' -T "my ssh session"
```

When I use the hotkey, a terminal window briefly appears and then immediately disappears.

How could I bind my sshpass command to a shortcut such that it will leave me with an open, interactive terminal?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try throwing the output of the command to a logfile (append `> /path/to/logfile` to the end of your call) and see if the command isn't failing quickly, thus closing the window. You could also add a sleep command at the end (like `; sleep 20`), to keep the window open a while longer for you to see what happened.

Comment: Thanks Zip, I've checked the command isn't failing. Saving it as a bash script and then setting the hotkey to execute this script (rather than having the hotkey run the command directly) resolves the issue. Others may have more insight into why this solution works.